# ASP.NET Rest API conventions sub resource post parameters

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, conventions

Good afternoon,

We have a small discussion here about REST conventions and to be honest I'm not sure what to do. I have for example the following resource:

> /reservation.

A post request to that url creates a new reservation. So far so good. But now I want to add a room to that reservation. So we have defined the following url:

> /reservation/{id}/room

As far as I know, this is not purely REST but it's ok(correct me if I'm wrong). If I want to add a room I create a post request with 3 / 4 parameters and fire it to that url. The problem is the id of the reservation:

- If I put it in the url it's actually a query string parameter, not a post parameter, so is that valid with the convention?
- When I do allow it to get it both from the query string als the body, than I my action has 2 parameters : the reservation id, and a wrapper object containing the other parameters. It's not against coding conventions, but it doesn't look nice..
- If I have the same parameter also in the body of my request, I defined it twice.

Do you guys know what the rest conventions say about this topic? I couldn't find a relevant topic about it.

Thanks in advance,

BHD

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'room' is a resource here. Also I don't think room should be always under a reservation. I think you should be able to query and created 'room' resource independent of the reservation.

Also reservation is a action when a 'person' (Assuming you have one such resource) wants a 'room'. So 'person' and 'room' are the real resources here. The 'reservation' can be treated as a resource that maps a 'person' to a 'room'. So a reservation would need these person and room ids.